# How to link profile field with multiple values?

Tags: profile, search, links

I would like to create a link to a pre-filtered profile search.
I have a field (custom_2) with multiple values.
I was able to link using one value (ex id=2) suing this url:
.../index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/profile&Itemid=45&_qf_Search_display=true&custom_2=2

However when I try the following I only get results of the last ID (ex. 1):
.../index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/profile&Itemid=145&_qf_Search_display=true&custom_2=2&custom_2=1

When using the following URL, I get the results of both values (2 and 1) but I also get an error:
.../index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/profile&Itemid=145&_qf_Search_display=true&custom_2[]=2&custom_2[]=1

Error:
Warning: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home1/.../public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Profile/Form/Search.php on line 65

Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in /home1/.../public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Profile/Form/Search.php on line 66

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home1/.../public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Profile/Form/Search.php on line 68

I'm not sure what to put in the URL to get rid of the error and get results from multiple value of the same field.

This is CiviCRM 4.7.29 on Joomla 3.8.3

Answer (score 0):

To pre-select multiple select value fields you can provide values with `,` separated.

Example:

```
.../index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/profile&Itemid=145&_qf_Search_display=true&custom_2=2,1
```

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: I can see the options with values 2 and 1 pre-preselected in the search form and it's not returning anything. Error" no matches found for ...

Comment: can you provide an example from demo site so this can be assessed by seeing a real example?

Comment: Yes, i could replicate on my 4.7.31 instance. The fields gets prepopulated but the force=1 doesn't respect